# Why is Intel C compiler failing to build coreutils?

Tags: compiler-errors, gnu, compiler-warnings, icc, gnu-coreutils

I am trying to build GNU coreutils 8.23 using Intel C compiler (icc 15.0.0), but fails to build due to the following error.

```
./lib/string.h(22): error #2282: unrecognized GCC pragma
  #pragma GCC system_header
```

I've already set `-w` to suppress all the warnings. However, this problem still remains. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try -no-gcc flag and see if it works.

This undefines the GNU macros.

Comment: Thanks, @VAndrei. It works, but the compiler generates other errors. Now I am not sure if the coreutils can be compiled with icc...

Comment: Theoretically I don't see why this can't be done. Practically I don't think it's quite straight forward.

Comment: Thanks, @VAndrei. I will post the solution if I can figure this out.